# Where Joins - Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have written and SQL Query that displays all the data in `Personnel` Table. I am trying to Fetch records only for a certain usergroup where `Personnel.UserGroup='AA'` i tried to add this into where condition where `Personnel.UserGroup='AA'`it doesnt show all the records for that user group, not sure where i am wrong

```
SELECT Youth.cyberid, Youth.LastName, Youth.FirstName, Youth.Level,
   Youth.CareManager, Personnel.Supervisor, Youth.StartDate,
   Youth.CloseDate
FROM (Youth
LEFT JOIN [Y Summary]
   ON Youth.[cyberid]   = [Y Summary].[cyberid])
INNER JOIN Personnel 
   ON Youth.CareManager = Personnel.PersonnelName, Personnel.PersonnelName
WHERE (((Youth.CloseDate) Is Null)
  And (([Y Summary].cyberid) Is Null)
  And ((Youth.CyberAdminOnly)<>True)) Or ((([Y Summary].cyberid) Is Null)
  And ((Youth.CyberAdminOnly)<>True)
  And ((Month(Youth.CloseDate))=Month(Date()))
  And ((Year(Youth.CloseDate))=Year(Date())));
```

Comment: You have personnel.personnel name duplicated in ON clause. Remove it and then try. Also try to make your query readable by using aliases and removing paranthesis

Comment: Please review formatting changes - as when I make the code readable it appears to be syntactically incorrect.